# C# Window Service Data Insertion From WEB SERVICE

Tags: c#, wcf, timer, windows-services, bulkinsert

I have a windows service that fetches data from WCF and it is working fine. I want to trigger the service after 5 minutes. If there are 10,000 records that have to be inserted - I want to avoid inserting duplicates. How can I increase the timer if the original insert isn't complete.

Below is my code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    try
    {
        m_mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        m_mainTimer.Interval = 10*60000;   // every ten min
        m_mainTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(main_function);
        m_mainTimer.AutoReset = false;  // makes it fire only once
        m_mainTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }           
}

public void main_function(object sender,ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            FetchRecord fn = new FetchRecord();
            fn.loadNotificationsInEcasDBFromSAP_CTRL();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {           
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != m_mainTimer)
            {
                m_mainTimer.Start(); // re - enable the timer
            }
        }
    }         
}    

protected override void OnStop()
{
    try
    {
        // Service stopped. Also stop the timer.
        m_mainTimer.Enabled = false;
        m_mainTimer = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to avoid inserting duplicate records and that is your major concern?

Comment: yes i want to avoid duplicate insertion and my major concern is how to increase timer if first call to the function is in progress?